# How to hook in a div block inside header block

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add a div inside adminhtml/default/default/page/header.phtml, specifically inside `<div class="header-right">.....</div>`. I know overriding header block would do this, but I don't want to do it that way. So that if someone adds admin theme it'll not mess his design. I'm looking for a solution like `jQuery('.header-right').append('<div>This is the div I want to add</div>');` in php which would add content at the end inside the `header-right` div. Maybe there is a way to parse the header block's html, add my content and replace there again.

I appreciate any hints/help.

```
<div class="header-top">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getHomeLink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/logo.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Magento Logo') ?>" class="logo"/></a>
    <div class="header-right">
        <p class="super">
         ........
         ........
         ........
        </p>
    </div>
   <div>This is the div I want to add</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prototype: http://jsfiddle.net/1sxsnkbb/

```
<body>
...
<div class="header-top">
    <a href="#">#</a>
    <div class="header-right">
        <p class="super">
         ........
         ........
         ........
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$$('.header-right')[0].setAttribute('id', 'header-right');
$('header-right').insert({'after':'<div>This is the div I want to add</div>'} );
</script>
...
</body>
```

Comment: Isn't possible without parsing full html before server response to client. Faster would be to edit required phtml

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with doing this somewhere at the bottom of your page?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

     jQuery('.header-right').empty().append('content to add');

 });
```

Comment: the wrong thing is, you'll need to have jquery used might be only for this purpose with prototypejs side by side. I don't like this solution.